# Permissions that need to be assigned for a RabbitMQ monitoring user

Tags: rabbitmq, monitoring

What permissions do I need to assign to a software, which will monitor my RabbitMQ server? The software agent should monitor most of the metrics explained and recommended in [this document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html#rabbitmq-metrics).

I think I have to create a user, e.g. `monitoring` and then give this user access to all `virtual hosts` which contain ressources that should be monitored.

I think when creating the user I have to assign it the **tag `monitoring`** which is a predefined tag.

What I do **not** understand is, what RegEx I need to assign to `configure`, `write` and `read`. The [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#permissions) contains a table with the permissions on **ressources**.

I think a monitoring software should **not** be able to **create or delete ressources** (`configure` permission) nor should it be able to **ADD** messages to a queue or **READ and ACK** messages from a queue. But for example it should be able to read the **number** of messages waiting in a queue to alert if a queue has a number of growing messages which are not retrieved.

Could anybody explain, what permissions and settings are required for such a monitoring user?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick guide from the beginning to the end while you are setting up RabbitMQ queues monitoring.

1) Create an account:

`rabbitmqctl add_user monitoring password`

2) Add monitoring tag (you can read more about RabbitMQ tags here https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

`rabbitmqctl set_user_tags monitoring monitoring`

3) Now get the names of your virtual hosts:

`rabbitmqctl list_vhosts`

4) Add permission for monitoring user to virtual host:

`rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p Some_Virtual_Host monitoring "" "" ""`

5) Check if access is granted successfully:

`curl -s -u monitoring:password http://localhost:15672/api/queues | jq`

*Look at the `"messages"` parameter*

Optional) You can publish a fake message from the command line:

`rabbitmqadmin publish --vhost=Some_Virtual_Host exchange=some_exchange routing_key=outgoing_routing_key payload="hello world"`

*Look at the `"messages"` again!*

Tip: make sure to enable rabbitmq_management plugin in your RabbitMQ build to be able to execute these queries.

Answer (score 3):

Figured that out myself with some testing. If someone is interested:

Create an account with `monitoring` tag
Add that account to EVERY vhost that should be monitored and add **empty strings** ("") to `configure`, `write` and `read` permissions.

With a nice bash script you can then for example get the numbers of messages in every queue:

```
curl -u username:password \
 --silent \
 http://<ServerOrIP>:15672/api/queues/<vhostname> | jq '.[] | .name, .messages'
```

Answer (score 0):

What is *jq*?  An explanation is missing from the answers provided above.

The jq command is in the EPEL repository.

https://www.cyberithub.com/how-to-install-jq-json-processor-on-rhel-centos-7-8/

```
# yum --enablerepo=epel install jq
```